# center an image in a custom minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

Sorry for my broken language, I'm a Frenchy !

I have to create a page template for a personal project :
a box without margins in the 72% of the page, aligned to the top which contains a big image vertically and horizontally centered, and after it, in the same page, restart with normal text.
I try to compose a command :

```
   \newcommand\inspic[1]{
   \newpage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \noindent
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.8cm}{-1.8cm}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\parwidth}
   \begin{minipage}[b][0.72\paperheight][b]{\paperwidth}
   \begin{center}
   \centerline{\includegraphics{#1}}
   \end{center}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{adjustwidth}
   }
```

but I can not center the image vertically.
Here an image to explain it :

[image: example]

a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\geometry{
a4paper,
lmargin=1.8cm,
rmargin=1.8cm,
tmargin=2cm,
bmargin=3cm
}

\newcommand\inspic[1]{
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.8cm}{-1.8cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\parwidth}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.72\paperheight][b]{\paperwidth}
\begin{center}
\centerline{\includegraphics{#1}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
}

\begin{document}
\inspic{mybigpicture}
\section*{title}
some text here
\end{document}
```

SOLUTION :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  lmargin=1.8cm,
  rmargin=1.8cm,
  tmargin=2cm,
  bmargin=3cm
}

\newcommand\inspic[1]{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \raisebox{2cm}[\dimexpr\height-2cm]{%
      \includegraphics[height=0.72\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}%
    }%
  }\par
}

\begin{document}
\inspic{fuukeicool}
\section*{title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) always post full minimal examples, here there are no preamble, so others cannot just copy your code and try it without having to add anything. Thus you are much less likely to get help unless to post something that compiles by it self.

Comment: thank you to remind me it, I'm new and I forget this point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a box `\textwidth` wide, which contains the picture raised by 2cm, but with its height trimmed by the same 2cm, so it will be placed at the very top of the page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  lmargin=1.8cm,
  rmargin=1.8cm,
  tmargin=2cm,
  bmargin=3cm
}

\newcommand\inspic[1]{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \raisebox{2cm}[\dimexpr\height-2cm]{%
      \includegraphics[height=0.72\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{#1}%
    }%
  }\par
}

\begin{document}
\inspic{example-image-a.pdf}
\section*{title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the picture is not as wide and high as the reserved box, for instance it's higher than wide, there's no difference, just don't specify the width:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  lmargin=1.8cm,
  rmargin=1.8cm,
  tmargin=2cm,
  bmargin=3cm
}

\newcommand\inspic[1]{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \raisebox{2cm}[\dimexpr\height-2cm]{%
      \includegraphics[height=0.72\paperheight]{#1}%
    }%
  }\par
}

\begin{document}
\inspic{example-image-9x16}
\section*{title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is perfect !
I remove the width argument for includegraphics, and add keepaspectratio.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very manual method.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) 
                {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.72\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \null

  \vspace{0.57\paperheight}   %% manually set this
  \noindent
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Harish Kumar, but the picture is not homotethic, and it is a problem.
If I remove the includegraphics argument for the width, the ratio is ok, but I cannot horizontally center it...

Comment: @krshk Sorry but what is homotethic?

Comment: Sorry, it's a transformation of something with the respect of proportionality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)

Comment: @krshk add `keepaspectratio` to the `height` and `width` options then it will be scaled to the largest possible size (same factor on both sides) that can possibly fit within the given width and height

Answer (score 1):

A dirty trick using a float (The minipage is framed in pale red to control their size):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,geometry,xcolor}
\geometry{lmargin=1.8cm,rmargin=1.8cm,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm}
\renewcommand{\textfloatsep}{0pt} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\color{red!10} %for testing only
\vspace{-2cm}\hfil\makebox[0pt][c]{%
\fbox{%for testing only
\begin{minipage}[t][.72\paperwidth]{.72\paperwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-25]
\end{document}
```

To fill completely the `minipage` or make the best fit possible use

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.72\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{myimage}
```

(You can still see some margin if you left the  `\fbox{}` because `\fboxsep` is not 0pt by default)

Comment: Thank you for your example Fran, but the aim is to have a picture with no margin, like in the thumbnails in my first post.

Comment: @krshk sorry but "vertically centered" confused me. Then simply increase the width of the image to `\linewidth` and add `height=.72\paperwidth`. Keep in mind the  daleif's comment about `keepaspectratio`.